# How to prevent hidden shapes from being exported to .stl file?

Tags: modifiers, export, 3d-printing, stl

I've created a replacement radiator knob in blender to get it 3d printed.

I've used array modifiers to replicate shapes mirrored around the center.
And I have used a Boolean modifier to create the notches for more grip.

The problem is that when I export to a .stl file the shapes that I have hidden use the "eye"-buttons also appear.

How can I remove them when exporting?

What it is supposed to look like after exporting:
[image: picture of what I made in blender]

What is looks like after exporting:
[image: picture of the exported .stl file]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before exporting, press <kbd>A</kbd> in object mode or go to *Select* > *All* to select everything. **Hidden objects won't be selected**.

Then while exporting, check "Selection Only" on the right to export only the selected objects.

[image]

Comment: Yes! it worked. Thank you!